# barra de progreso no se muestra video javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hola estaba siguiendo un tutorial pero la barra de progreso no me aparece, estos son las hojas de trabajo, en la funcion "cliclando" donde puse "bucle = setInterval(estado, 1000); " es donde se deberia ir mostrando la barra de progreso del video pero no pasa nada.

> RESUELTO, falta un "=" en la linea function estado(){
>     if(**mivideo.ended=false**)....

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Eventos en html5 con js</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="18aspecto_videos.css">
    <script src="18funcionalidad_barra.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <!--MANERA MAS OPTIMA PARA PONER LOS VIDEOS-->
    <section id="video">
        <video id="mivideo" width="720" loop> 
            <source src="videos/17video-2012-04-05-14-22-32.mp4">
            <source src="videos/17video-2012-04-05-14-22-32.ogg">
        </video>

        <nav> <!--especifican barras de navegacion y controloes de navegacion para un video-->
            <div id="botones">
                <button type="button" id="reproducir">play</button>
            </div>

            <div id ="barra">
                <div id="progreso">

                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </section>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
#video{
    width: 720px;
    margin: :20px auto;
    background: #FC3;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 2px solid #F60;

    -moz- border-radius: 8px; /* para mejorar la compatiblidad*/
    -webkit- border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px;
}

nav{
    margin: 5px 0;
}

#botones{
    float:left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 20px;
}

#barra{
    background: #FFF;
    width: 600px;
    height: 16px;
    border:1px solid #666;
    padding: 3px;
    margin-left: 80px;
}

#progreso{
    position: absolute; /*lo dejara a la izq de donde se encuentra ahora*/
    width: 0px;
    height: 16px;
    background: rgba(0,0,150,2);
}
```

JS

```
var mivideo, reproducir, barra, progreso,maximo;
maximo = 600; /*definí que la barra de carga tendria un ancho de 600 px por eso digo que max es de 600*/

function comenzar(){
    mivideo=document.getElementById("mivideo"); /*hago referencia desde js a las vriables y que sepa que nos referimos a los elementos del codigo html (las que estan entre '')*/
    reproducir=document.getElementById("reproducir");
    barra=document.getElementById("barra");
    progreso=document.getElementById("progreso");

    reproducir.addEventListener("click",clicando,false);

    progreso.addEventListener("click",adelantando,false);
}

function clicando(){
    if((mivideo.paused==false) && (mivideo.ended==false)){ /*si esta reproduciendo*/
        mivideo.pause();
        reproducir.innerHTML="Play"; /*cambia el texto del boton cuando este pausado*/
    }
    else{ /*si esta pausado o esta finalizado*/
        mivideo.play();
        reproducir.innerHTML="Pause"; /*cambia el texto del boton cuando este reproduciendo*/

        bucle = setInterval(estado, 1000); 
    }
}


function adelantando(){

}

function estado(){
    if(mivideo.ended=false)
    {
        var total = parseInt(mivideo.currentTime*maximo/mivideo.duration); 
        progreso.style.width =total+"px"; 
    }
}

window.addEventListener("load",comenzar,false);
```

Comment: Te saca algún error en Consola ?

Comment: qué consola :| ? (uso sublime text para escribir el codigo solamente) no no me da ningun error simplemente la barra de carga del video no funciona

Comment: Clic derecho en la página, clic en inspeccionar, luego clic en console y ahí te salen todos los posibles errores que puedas tener en tu javascript, realiza los pasos y me dices si sale algún error

Comment: @CamiloVasquez Sale en blanco amigo, creo que no hay error

Comment: No hay errores tienes razón, cambia esto progreso.style.width =total+"px";  por esto progreso.style.width += total+"px";

Comment: Nop, tampoco funciona, en el video lo colocaron asi tambien =total+...
por mas que busco el error no encuentro :S el video es "Curso HTML 5. Inserción Vídeos III. Vídeo 19" del canal Pildorasinformaticas, no sé porque no me funciona xd leí los comentarios y soy el unico al parecer...

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69148/discussion-between-camilo-vasquez-and-ricardobarros).

Comment: ¿Pudiste solucionar el asunto? Yo tengo tu mismo problema y buscando soluciones llegué hasta acá... jjaja!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu error básicamente se encuentra en la siguiente línea:

```
if(mivideo.ended=false)
```

Como estás haciendo una condición debes utilizar un operador de comparación y no un operador de asignación, recuerda:

Un igual `=` es un [operador de asignación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Assignment_Operators)

Dos `==` o tres iguales `===` son [operadores de comparación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Comparison_Operators)

Teniendo esto en cuenta la sintaxis de tu `if` debería de ser la siguiente:

```
if(mivideo.ended==false)
```

Comment: gracias!! funcionando.

Comment: Te invito a que te hagas el [tour] para que termines de entender el funcionamiento básico del sitio, saludos !

Comment: @CamiloVasquez Hola :) puedes analizar [mi pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/119422/el-buffer-no-carga-en-la-barra-de-progreso-video-player-jquery) sí... Saludos!